# Why does it not pass data when I pass bundle from one activity to another in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle, multiscreen

I am trying to pass private String from MainActivity to another activity. Here is the code:

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String data1;
private String data2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Direct to data Input page and then to the next page
    TextView text = findViewById(R.id.data_text);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.datalayout);
            EditText data = findViewById(R.id.Data1);
            MainActivity.this.data1 = data.getText().toString();
            data = findViewById(R.id.Data2);
            MainActivity.this.data2 = data.getText().toString();
            v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.continueNext);
            MainActivity.this.redirectToAnotherPage(v, MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);

        }
    });

private void redirectToAnotherPage(View view, final Context baseActivity, final Class newActivity) {
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(baseActivity, newActivity);
            //Pass data between MainActivity and the launching activity using bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Data1",data1);
            bundle.putString("Data2",data2);
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            //End MainActivity before starting new activity
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

***AnotherActivity***

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page);

    //Get data from MainActivity using Bundle
    Bundle viewData = getIntent().getExtras();
    String dataToInclude = viewData.getString("Data1");
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dataToInclude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
    toast.show();
}
```

When I pass data1 & data2, which are of String type, I do not see the toast message. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello, this code looks fine and will pass the string without any errors. Can you post your full code for ```MainActivity```  perhaps so that we could see where the error occurs

Comment: already did that when  raj asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomprehensible:  
1) what are you doing? `setContentView(R.layout.datalayout);`

2) What is `data` in `data.getText().toString();`

If you see the toast with no text in it that means that `dataToInclude` is either `null` or empty.  
So focus to check `data1` and `data2` variables.

**Edit**: When you click on `text` the listener is executed immediately:  
 
the new layout is shown with empty EditTexts, their empty strings are stored in `data1` and `data2` and you open the new activity with empty strings in the bundle.

Comment: 1)datalayout is the page that shows edittext fields for the user to input the data 2)edittext returns charsequence, so I have to convert to string

Comment: So you change the layout of the activity?

Comment: no . It is more like inserting a layout in between two layouts. Here is my purpose. I have 2 items and when clicked on one of them, it opens their appropriate app page. but in between the main page and the app page, I want to collect variables from the user and then on another click, proceed to the appropriate page. Thus, I have used two onclick listeners

Comment: And you're using setContentView? Couldn't you use an invisible layout and make it visible? Anyway if you don't post full code you can't get help. What is data since it is not declared in the activity?

Comment: made some changes. would this help?

Comment: @KiranCK what is going on here? For one hour you presented wrong code?

Comment: the top method has nothing to do with the error. as the bundle is carried out with the second activity, i just pasted oncreate method for reference.

Comment: @KiranCK What are you talking about? You're passing the values of 
findViewById(R.id.Data1); and findViewById(R.id.Data2); with the bundle that could be empty and you think that this has nothing to do with your problem?

Comment: You just shed some light. I was just checking the second method for values. I guess I had to see the first method now. I am really sorry for not being careful enough about the first method.Thank you

Comment: still what do you mean?

Comment: the bundle is empty when it is passed to another activity. but i am typing some values on edittext.. why does it not get saved to data1 or data2?

Comment: k. got it. I have to use the edittext in the second method

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling toast.show(). Do like this -

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dataToInclude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dataToInclude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I had that already. I should've been more clear, when I said I can not see the toast message. I can see the toast, but not the message inside it.

Comment: I did that. I just missed to paste it here. That is not the problem. I can see the toast but it is just a blank toast. no value is shown in toast

Comment: I've added the full code as you asked. toast is not my intention, i just used it to see if i get the values passed to toast

Comment: MainActivity.this.data1 = data.getText().toString(); - What is data here and where you have initialized or created it ? @KiranCK

Comment: that is an edittext. I manually enter the values in the app and store it to the variable data1.

Comment: Is it present in main activity layout or data layout ? Where have you initialized data ?? Try to log the value of data and see if something appears..

Comment: Here is my purpose. I have 2 items and when clicked on one of them, it opens their appropriate app page. but in between the main page and the app page, I want to collect variables from the user and then on another click, proceed to the appropriate page. Thus, I have used two onclick listeners. I have in initialized data in the onCreate() method

Comment: I made some changes. would this help?

Answer (score 0):

You may just use putExtra method on intent like following

```
myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
```

and in the other activity just get the data with intent as follwing

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```